# Pythonerror while web extraction: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

having

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

for following code

```
urlpage = 'fasttrack.co.uk/league-tables/tech-track-100/league-table'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
    # find results within table
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tableSorter'})
    results = table.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: urlpage =  'http://www.fasttrack.co.uk/league-tables/tech-track-100/league-table/'

Comment: if my answer helps, dont forget to tick the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate through the source code of the url, you will find that the table tag is:

```
<table class="tableSorter2">
```

So instead of:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tableSorter'})
```

use:

```
table = soup.find('table',class_="tableSorter2")
#or
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "tableSorter2"})
```

Answer (score -1):

That means that the variable `table` is null (None), most likely because `soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'tableSorter'})` can't find that element